# SymPy: how can i get the partial derivatives of one equation input beforehand by the user?

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation, derivative

Im trying to build a constrained optimization calculator in python using the sympy module. The idea is that a user can enter two functions, "f" and "g", which then are put together to form the equation "L".

I want SymPy to give me the partial derivatives of x, y and lambda in "L", however my code does not seem to be working. When trying to get their partial derivatives i get the following results:

0

0

-x - 4*y + 500

I used x+100*y-y**2 as function 1 and x+4*y-500 and function 2.

Heres the code so far:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.parsing import sympy_parser
x, y = sp.symbols("x y", real=True)
lam = sp.symbols('lambda', real=True)
insert = input("Insert function 1:") #function 1
f = sympy_parser.parse_expr(insert)  #transforming the function into a sympy expression
print(f)
insert2 = input("Insert function 2:") #function2
g = sympy_parser.parse_expr(insert2)  #transforming function 2
L = f - lam*g #getting the equation "L"
xx = sp.diff(L, x) #partial derivative L'x
yy = sp.diff(L, y) #partial derivative L'y
ll = sp.diff(L, lam) #partial derivative L'lam
print(xx)
print(yy)
print(ll)
```

I have tried both the "parse_expr" and "simpify" commands to transform the functions input by the user from string to sympy expressions. I might be missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your local `x` and `y` are real but those that the parser returns are vanilla, they have not assumptions. Since symbols match by name and assumptions, your input functions don't have (the same) `x` and `y`:

```
>>> f.has(x)
False
```

So either don't make your local symbols real

```
>>> var('x')
x
>>> f = sympy_parser.parse_expr(insert)
>>> f.has(x)
True
```

Or pass your local symbols to the parser so it can use them to build your functions:

```
>>> f = sympy_parser.parse_expr(insert, dict(x=x,y=y))
>>> f.has(x)
True
```

And once you are using the same symbols, the rest of your issues should move to a new level :-)

Comment: Thats exactly the answer i was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it works. This is common "gotcha".